# Given some text input, find the largest anagram groups

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, anagram

I have been working on an assignment and am required with an input containing words composed of lowercase alphabetic characters, separated by whitespace(or new line). It is terminated by the word “STOP”. You can assume there will be no more than 100 words, and each word does not exceed 20 characters long.

Output the 5 largest anagram groups. If there are less than 5 groups, output them all. Sort the groups by decreasing size. Break ties lexicographically by the lexicographical smallest element. For each group output, print its size and its member words. Sort the member words lexicographically and print equalwords only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ReadWord(char [21]);
void SortWord(char [21]);
void AssignAnagramGroup(int);
void SortWordList();
void CalculateTopFiveGroups();
int isAnagram(char [21], char [21]);

char wordlist[100][21];  //stores list of words
int anagramgroup[100];  //for each word, store the group id it belongs to
int anagramgroupcount=1; //how many groups do we have
int anagramgroupsize[101];  //for each anagramgroup, we store size
int wordcount=0; //how many words were in the list
int largestfive[5]={0}; //stores top 5 anagramgroups
int groupsizeorder[100]; //array to hold the groupsize in corresponding word placement
int main ()
{
 char word[21];
 int done = 0;
 int i, j, k;
 int x=1;
 do
 {
    ReadWord(word);
        if (strcmp(word, "STOP")==0 || wordcount > 99)
            break;

    strcpy(wordlist[wordcount++], word);
    AssignAnagramGroup(wordcount-1);

}while(!done);

for (i=0; i<wordcount; i++){
    printf ("ReadWord: Wordlist[%d]=\"%s\"      AnagramGroup=%d\n", i, wordlist[i], anagramgroup[i]);}
    printf ("WordList size=%d words\n", wordcount);
    for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
        if (anagramgroupsize[i]!=0)
            printf ("Anagram Group %d of size %d\n",    i, anagramgroupsize[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    SortWordList();
    CalculateTopFiveGroups();

for (i=0; i<wordcount; i++){
    printf ("Wordlist[%d]=\"%s\"   Gid=%d   Gsize=%d\n",    i, wordlist[i], anagramgroup[i], groupsizeorder[i]);}
 //THIS IS WHAT NEEDS CHANGING****
 for (i=0; i<5 && largestfive[i+1]!=0; i++){
    printf("Group size of: %d ", largestfive[i+1]);
    printf("\n");
 }

 return 0;
}

void ReadWord(char word [])
{
 scanf ("%s", word);
}

void AssignAnagramGroup (int wordcount)
{
 int j;
    if (wordcount==0)
    {
        anagramgroup[0]=1;
        anagramgroupsize[1]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j=0; j<wordcount; j++)
        {
            if (isAnagram(wordlist[wordcount],  wordlist[j]) ==1)
            {
                anagramgroup[wordcount]=anagramgroup[j];
                anagramgroupsize[anagramgroup[j]]+=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (j==wordcount){
                anagramgroup[wordcount]=++anagramgroupcount;
            anagramgroupsize[anagramgroup[j]]+=1;
        }
 }
    return;
}   

int isAnagram (char word1[],char word2[])
{
   int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;

   while (word1[c] != '\0')
   {
      first[word1[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }
   c = 0;

   while (word1[c] != '\0')
   {
      second[word2[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      if (first[c] != second[c])
         return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}

void SortWordList()
{
 int i, j, k, temp;
 char tempchar[21];
    for (i=0; i<wordcount; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<wordcount-1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(wordlist[j], wordlist[j+1])>0){
                strcpy(tempchar, wordlist[j]);
                strcpy(wordlist[j], wordlist[j+1]);
                strcpy(wordlist[j+1], tempchar);

                temp=anagramgroup[j];
                anagramgroup[j]=anagramgroup[j+1];
                anagramgroup[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

 for (i=0; i<wordcount; i++)
    groupsizeorder[i]=anagramgroupsize[anagramgroup[i]];
 return;
}

void CalculateTopFiveGroups()
{
 int i, j, temp;
 int anagramtemp[101]={0};
 for (i=1; i<=anagramgroupcount; i++){
    anagramtemp[i]=anagramgroupsize[i];
 }

    for (i=0; i<anagramgroupcount; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<anagramgroupcount-i; j++) {
            if (anagramtemp[j+1]<anagramtemp[j+2]){
                temp=anagramtemp[j+1];
                anagramtemp[j+1]=anagramtemp[j+2];
                anagramtemp[j+2]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
 for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
    largestfive[i]=anagramtemp[i];
 }
return; 
}
```

I currently have the output

```
ReadWord: WordList[0]="ate" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[1]="eta" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[2]="colli" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[3]="icoll" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[4]="eat" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[5]="lloci" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[6]="cat" AnagramGroup=3
ReadWord: WordList[7]="tac" AnagramGroup=3
WordList size=8 words
Anagram Group 1 of size 3
Anagram Group 2 of size 3
Anagram Group 3 of size 2

WordList[0]="ate" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[1]="cat" Gid=3 Gsize=2
WordList[2]="colli" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[3]="eat" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[4]="eta" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[5]="icoll" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[6]="lloci" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[7]="tac" Gid=3 Gsize=2
Group of size 3
Group of size 3
Group of size 2
```

This is what I need the output to contain

```
ReadWord: WordList[0]="ate" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[1]="eta" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[2]="colli" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[3]="icoll" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[4]="eat" AnagramGroup=1
ReadWord: WordList[5]="lloci" AnagramGroup=2
ReadWord: WordList[6]="cat" AnagramGroup=3
ReadWord: WordList[7]="tac" AnagramGroup=3
WordList size=8 words
Anagram Group 1 of size 3
Anagram Group 2 of size 3
Anagram Group 3 of size 2

WordList[0]="ate" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[1]="cat" Gid=3 Gsize=2
WordList[2]="colli" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[3]="eat" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[4]="eta" Gid=1 Gsize=3
WordList[5]="icoll" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[6]="lloci" Gid=2 Gsize=3
WordList[7]="tac" Gid=3 Gsize=2
Group of size 3:[GID: 1] ate eat eta
Group of size 3:[GID: 2] colli icoll lloci
Group of size 2:[GID: 3] cat tac
```

I'm pretty sure that I need to change the last print in main that has been marked with //THIS IS WHAT NEEDS CHANGING****

If anybody cant assist me, and figure out how to make the last print statement correct, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your specific example, but has a few errors when using other examples. Maybe it'll help though.

```
`do {
    ReadWord(word); 
    if (strcmp(word, "STOP") == 0 || wordcount > 99) // if STOP is entered or 100 words have been read
        break;                   // the input loop will be exited
    strcpy(wordlist[wordcount++], word);         // assigns words read in to the word list
    AssignAnagramGroup(wordcount-1);         // assigns word read in to an anagram group
} while (!done);    // forever loop, only exits on break condition

SortWordList(); // sorts the word list
TopFiveGroups(); // finds the top five largest groups

for (i=0; i<wordcount; i++) {
    printf ("Wordlist[%d] = \"%s\"  AnagramGroup= %d, Gsize=%d\n", i, wordlist[i], anagramgroup[i], groupsizeorder[i]);
}
printf("Wordlist size = %d words \n", wordcount);

for (i=0; i<5 && largest[i+1] != 0; i++) {      // prints other stuff

    printf("Anagram Group %d of size %d ", i+1, largest[i+1]);
    for (j=0; j<wordcount; j++)                 // prints words
        if (anagramgroup[j] == i+1)
            printf("%s ", wordlist[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;`
```